# sending message notifications with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase to send notification to users when they receive new messages from other users. for now i only have a simple text that tells users that they have a new message but instead of that i would like to retrieve the actual message from the database and display it as the notification body. but i don't really know how to point to the message body inside the database.

this is my database structure

[image: message database]

this is my firebase function

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Listens for new messages added to messages/
exports.messageNotification = functions.database.ref('/MsgNotifications/{user_id}/{message_id}').onWrite( (change, context) => {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
 const message_id = context.params.message_id;

 console.log('We Have A Message for :', user_id);

 if (!change.after.val()){
  return console.log("A Notification Has Been Deleted From The Database: ", message_id)
 }

 const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/MsgNotifications/${user_id}/${message_id}`).once('value');

 return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

  const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
  console.log("You have new message from : ", from_user_id)

  const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

   const userName = result[0].val();
   const token_id = result[1].val();

   const payload = {
    notification: {
     title: "New Message",
     body: `You have a new message from ${userName}`,
     icon: "default",
     click_action: "com.chat.qchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
    },
    data: {
     from_user_id: from_user_id
    }
   };
  
   return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload ).then(Response =>{ 
    console.log('this is the notification')
   });


  });
   
 });

});
```

Comment: You're using quite a few complex technologies in this code, and have quite a bit of non-trivial code. This makes it hard to help, since we have to first understand this code, and then figure out where you are struggling.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same problem with a simpler piece of code, that uses fewer technologies? For example: can you get the same problem without FCM? And maybe even without Cloud Functions, just in Node.js or a web page? Reducing the context needed for the problem will make it much more likely that someone can help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).